# I want to conserve the images' order and position

Tags: html, css

I'm working in a project thelifeofthings.ca it still unfinished. The code is too long to post it. What I want to accomplish is having 10 columns and 5 rows in any desktop screen regardless of its resolution.

All the images CSS is like `

```
 #image {
float:left;
width: 142px;
height: 162px;
background-image: url('http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
transition-property: background-image;
transition-delay: 2s;
transition-duration: 0.1s;

}`
```

and the html is simply

```
<a href="#" class="lightbox_trigger"><div id="image2"></div></a>
```

So I create it following my browser's size but in other laptops it shows different number of columns and rows

Comment: Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of this error. If the code is too long, you can post the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out the site; the quick fix for this (relative to your schema) is

```
a > div {
    width: 9.8vw !important;
}
```

Basically, you can use the viewport width unit (vw) to specify the amount of units relative to the viewport. 100vw should equal the entire viewport width, so 10vw for each element should be what you're looking for.

However, there is an issue with the scroll bar when using Windows, so that's why I used 9.8vw instead of 10vw (above).

For more info regarding viewport units, and the problem with the scroll bar, see this link:
https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/